# How to connect a SONY PSP system to ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, unity, usb, files, connection

I tried to connect my SONY PSP e1004 on to my UBUNTU 12.10 desktop,But no result.Nothing happens.What will I do? I must connect my PSP to computer for file and games sharing.Tell me what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link explaining you how to do it:

[PSP to ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PSP)

Comment: I think that will work.. But When I try to install it I don't really understand how to install that tar.gz package !!!